Efficient coordinate indexing
I have a triangle list, that has XYZ cooridnates per triangle node. I need a list of nodes and a list of triangle node indices from that. Close nodes should get the same index.
My C# code is:
        // ensureNodeAt
        // return node index. Avoid duplicates.
        public int ensureNodeAt(XYZ p, double eps_dist = 1e-9)
        {
            // backwards - most likely the one we seek is at the back
            for (int i = nodes.Count - 1; i >= 0; --i)
            {
                XYZ v = nodes[i].v - p;
                // dx = v.X - p.X;
                // dy = v.Y - p.Y;
                // dz = v.Z - p.Z;
                // dx = dx * dx + dy * dy + dz * dz;
                if (v.X * v.X + v.Y * v.Y + v.Z * v.Z < eps_dist)
                { return i; }
            }
            // Must add a new node
            nodes.Add(p);
            return nodes.Count - 1;
        }

        void work(List<XYZ> triangles){
            tri = new List<Tri>(triangles.Count / 3); // triangle indices
            nodes = new List<XYZ>(triangles.Count); // triangle nodes
            for (int i = 0; i < triangles.Count; i += 3)
            {
                var a = triangles[i];
                var b = triangles[i + 1];
                var c = triangles[i + 2];
                tri.Add(new Tri(ensureNodeAt(a, eps_dist), ensureNodeAt(b, eps_dist), ensureNodeAt(c, eps_dist)));
            }
        }


Is there any way to make this faster or run in parallel? I have like 900k of nodes.

Put coordinates into some space partition structure, for example - kd-tree.

In order for nodes to be flagged as duplicates they must have X within eps_dist. So if you keep your points sorted by X, then you won't need to check so many for duplicates.
You can sweep the sorted collection until nodes[i].v.X >=  p.X-eps_dist, then start testing distances for duplicates, then stop when nodes[i].v.X > p+eps_dist.
The same is true of Y or Z; so you could use one of those instead of X if you have reason to think points will be more separated in one of those directions.

Good idea. But I want the indices of previoulsy added points not to change. See my "answer".

Here's how I solved it. My data is mostly X,Y data with slight Z offsets, so grouping the points by x ranges did the trick for me:
namespace Whatever
{
    using System;
    using System.Collections.Generic;
    using WhateverXYZ; // class XYZ

    public class SpacePartitioning
    {
        // PUBLIC
        public double eps = 1e-3; // max error for neighbour nodes, so they are "the same"
        public List<XYZ> nodes;

        // PRIVATE
        // A Space is a list of node indices within a range xmin/xmax.
        // nodes very close to xmin/xmax are in both neighbour spaces,
        // so finding a close node is ensured for both neighbour spaces.
        class Space
        {
            public Space(int perSpaceNodes) { xmin = 0; xmax = 0; indices = new List<int>(perSpaceNodes); }
            public double xmin, xmax; // the bounds of the space are extendes by +/- eps to check if a point is inside
            public List<int> indices;
            public double Width() { return xmax - xmin; }
        }
        private List<Space> spaces;
        int perSpaceNodes = 128; // desired masimum number of nodes per space
        const double minSpaceWidth = 2.0; // [ft] the minimum width of a space, even if it has lots of nodes

        // C'tor
        public SpacePartitioning(int nodeCountPreallocation = 1000000)
        {
            Clear(nodeCountPreallocation);
        }

        // Clear
        public void Clear(int nodeCountPreallocation = 1000000)
        {
            // keep the number of nodes per spaces lower than the number of nodes
            int sideLength = (int)Math.Sqrt(nodeCountPreallocation);
            perSpaceNodes = Math.Max(128, Math.Min(4096, sideLength / 8));

            nodes = new List<XYZ>(nodeCountPreallocation);
            spaces = new List<Space>(64);
        }



        // PUBLIC

        // Find or add a node to the list of nodes.
        // Specify this.eps before starting to add nodes.
        // Returns the index in m_nodes[]
        public int FindOrAddNode(XYZ p)
        {
            double eps2 = eps * eps;

            EnsureSpacesFor(p);

            foreach (var space in spaces)
            {
                if (IsPointInSpace(space, p))
                {
                    foreach (var ix in space.indices)
                    {
                        if (dist2(nodes[ix], p) < eps2) { return ix; }
                    }

                    // Point must go in this space
                    return InsertPointToSpaces(p);
                }
            }

            int can_t_be = 1;
            return -1;
        }


        // squared distance of two points
        private static double dist2(XYZ p1, XYZ p2)
        {
            XYZ d = p2 - p1;
            return d.X * d.X + d.Y * d.Y + d.Z * d.Z;
        }

        // Split a space with many nodes into two spaces with only half of the nodes, each.
        private void SplitLargeSpace(Space spc)
        {
            if (spc.Width() < minSpaceWidth) { return; }

            // find average point center
            double xavg = 0.0;
            foreach (int ix in spc.indices) { xavg += nodes[ix].X; }
            xavg /= (double)spc.indices.Count;

            // split space
            Space sp2 = new Space(perSpaceNodes);
            sp2.xmin = xavg;
            sp2.xmax = spc.xmax;
            spc.xmax = xavg;

            // reasign nodes to the corresponding spaces
            for (int i = 0; i < spc.indices.Count; i++)
            {
                int ix = spc.indices[i];
                XYZ p = nodes[ix];
                
                // both can be possible!

                // remove from old space
                if (!IsPointInSpace(spc, p))
                {
                    spc.indices.RemoveAt(i);
                    --i;
                }

                // add in new space
                if (IsPointInSpace(sp2, p))
                {
                    sp2.indices.Add(ix);
                }
            }
            spaces.Add(sp2);
        }


        // Adds point to nodes list and then puts the reference in any space
        private int InsertPointToSpaces(XYZ p)
        {
            // add new point to the point list
            int ix = nodes.Count;
            nodes.Add(p);

            // insert new point to spaces
            foreach (var space in spaces)
            {
                if (IsPointInSpace(space, p))
                {
                    space.indices.Add(ix);
                }
            }

            // split large spaces
            for (int i = 0; i < spaces.Count; i++)
            {
                var space = spaces[i];
                if (space.indices.Count >= perSpaceNodes)
                {
                    SplitLargeSpace(space);
                }
            }
            return ix;
        }

        // Esnure, the spaces containers are wide enough to capture the point
        private void EnsureSpacesFor(XYZ p)
        {
            const double largeWidth = 10000.0; // "infinite" range for new spaces

            // empty space
            if (spaces.Count == 0)
            {
                var ns = new Space(perSpaceNodes);
                ns.xmin = p.X - largeWidth;
                ns.xmax = p.X + largeWidth;
                spaces.Add(ns);
            }

            // left of all spaces
            if (spaces[0].xmin > p.X + eps)
            {
                var ns = new Space(perSpaceNodes);
                ns.xmin = p.X - largeWidth;
                ns.xmax = spaces[0].xmin;
            }
            // right of all spaces
            if (spaces[spaces.Count - 1].xmax < p.X - eps)
            {
                var ns = new Space(perSpaceNodes);
                ns.xmin = spaces[spaces.Count - 1].xmax;
                ns.xmax = p.X + largeWidth;
            }
        }

        // Is a point within the space (including some extra space for nodes close to the boundary of a space)
        bool IsPointInSpace(Space space, XYZ p) { return p.X >= space.xmin - eps && p.X <= space.xmax + eps; }

    }
}

